# New to XAML. What does the x: and :x mean?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to XAML. And I wonder what all the x: and :x are all about. Tutorials about XAML does not explain this (or I haven't read enough yet).

For example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.WPF_Application.ResourceSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="ResourceSample" Height="150" Width="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="strHelloWorld">Hello, world!</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource strHelloWorld}" FontSize="56" />
        <TextBlock>Just another "<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource strHelloWorld}" />" example, but with resources!</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

What does x mean in these lines?

- Window **x**:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.WPF_Application.ResourceSample"
- xmlns:**x**="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" sys:String
- **x**:Key="strHelloWorld">Hello, world!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This defines a namespace mapping, i.e. the prefix `x` maps to the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml` namespace:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Please refer to MSDN for more information about XAML namespaces and namespace mappings.

**XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml

You might change `x` into something else if you want to:

[x: meaning in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573782/x-meaning-in-xaml)

As mentioned, it is just a prefix that is mapped to a namespace in order for you to be able to use a type or attribute that is defined in the namespace in your XAML markup.